# Django Broken pipe with send_mail in browser and shell

Tags: python, django, shell, email, mezzanine

I am running into issues while trying to get Django and mezzanine to send email notifications from a contact form. I know the form is working as it is adding the inputted data into the database I am just then running into a constant loading situation on the browser where it is always waiting for the host to send it something at this point I often get the issue of broken pipe from googling it I find this is a known issue although I am using 1.6.5 that I see no reference to the issue with this version. I then tried to use the send mail function in shell like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460614/sending-email-from-django-mezzanine-running-on-heroku) for me this fails also sometimes with a broken pipe and sometimes it just hangs. Bellow are my settings for email.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

# Host for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

# Port for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_PORT = 587

# Optional SMTP authentication information for EMAIL_HOST.
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that you use to send the email?

Comment: 2nd petkostas request; also, have you tried swapping email_backend for one of the debug ones (i.e. console) just to be sure it's definitely email related.

Comment: take a look at the link above that answers both your questions it shows I have done it through shell.

Comment: The other code is default mezzanine contact form code not sure where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly figured it out not sure how what I did makes a difference but it seemed to make it work when sending emails. What I did was reorder the settings this should have no effect I know but I moved the `ÈMAIL_USE_TLS` to the top of the defined list then restarted the server and it then worked perfectly with no issues sending out emails with no issues at all. Not much of a fix but it did work. Not quite sure why yet if I figure it out I will let you know.